# Text and JLabel

Tags: java, text, position, jlabel

I have a JLabel which contains a picture and I set a text to this JLabel using the setText method. My problem is that I want to choose the position of the text I have just set. Do you have any ideas to perform that ?

```
//This the code i have
this.label = new JLabel ();
this.label.setText("My text");
this.label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
this.add(label);
```

Comment: What do u mean by position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
public class LabelTextPos extends JLabel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LabelTextPos label = new LabelTextPos();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Sample", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want use JLabel.LEFT, I would like to set the position of my text with a X and Y position without the JLabel constant LEFT or BOTTOM ...

Comment: You have to implement custom Jlabel. Added sample code above.

Comment: Thx, that's what i want. :)